RabbitMQ mirrored classic queues replication strategy
We are currently using RabbitMQ with mirrored queues (high availability policy). Initially, we assumed that mirrored queues employed synchronized replication. However, recent research suggests that replication is actually performed asynchronously. I reviewed RabbitMQ's official documentation but couldn’t find a definitive statement about whether the replication is synchronous or asynchronous. However, the documentation does mention that mirrored queues are not considered reliable and recommends migrating to quorum queues.
Could you please confirm if the following description of the replication process for RabbitMQ mirrored queues is accurate?

A producer sends a message to a queue, which is first received by the master node of the queue.
The master node acknowledges the message to the producer once it has been persisted locally.
The message is then replicated to mirror nodes asynchronously.

